# Sharepoint 2010 critical event 6398

Tags: sharepoint-2010, windows-sbs-2011

I've just installed SBS 2011 and every 30 minutes this is logged (note: it's a swedish server, this is my translation, might not be phrased identically on english systems):

```
Logname:       Application
Source:        Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Foundation
Date:          2011-04-04 10:00:00
Event-ID:      6398
Category:      Timer
Level:         Critical
Keyword:     
User:          DOMAIN\spfarm
Computer:      SERVER.domain.local
Description:
An exception occured for runtime of jobdefinition Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUsageImportJobDefinition (ID 1abcd25a-5d73-49df-a757-c440b10364a3). More information below.

Access to path SERVER-20110402-1559a.usage denied.
```

There are plenty of google results for the same event id but different error ("access denied to Program files\Common files\Microsoft shared\Web server extensions\14\LOGS", had that error, but fixed it following the instructions given on the web), but I cannot find any reference at all to this error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there still is an access denied issue. The user DOMAIN\spfarm is trying to write the *.usage files to the LOGS directory. Have you changed any permissions of DOMAIN\spfarm manually or manually changed the account of the SharePoint Timer service?

Comment: There was indeed still a permissions issue on the logs directory. I didn't understand from the message which directory was wrongly setup however, so thank you!